# Bake mesh to plane results in flipped image

Tags: baking

I'm trying to bake the top face of the cube(with text) to the upper plane like below,

[image]

Then I place the plane on top of the text and do a ray cast,

[image]

[image]

The end result is a flipped over result,

[image]

I'm curious what happened, I used to bake from high poly to low poly, but this is the first time I bake a chosen high poly face to a plane, could you suggest me a right way of doing this, thank you my friend, I just want to bake a simple decal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the uv shell of the plane is flipped. Try scaling the shell in the uv editor in -X.

Comment: Thank you so much, but is it the plane's uv is flipped by default?

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, I've hat flipped uv shells when making Cube Projections.